# Show BottomSheet after change the layout

Tags: java, android

I have a `BottomSheet` "buttomSheet" (in this sheet it is a list view that is `GONE`) and a normal `Button` "btnShowListView" (out from the "buttomSheet").
I want that when I click on "btnShowListView" the list view in the bottomSheet will be `Visible` its work but only after 2 clicks on button "btnShowListView"...
this is my code:

```
    final View bottomSheetView = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetLayout);
    listView = (ListView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    buttomSheet = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView);
    btnShowListView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bottomSheetView.requestLayout();
            bottomSheetView.invalidate();
            bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
   });
```

Comment: Please post your xml part too

Answer (score 0):

You can make the listview already visible, there's no need to hide it; you can get te same effect by setting the state of the bottom sheet behavior to HIDDEN.
I tested the code below and it should work also for you.

```
final View bottomSheetView = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetLayout);

bottomSheetBehavior= BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView);
bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

btnShowListView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }
});
```

Comment: But I want that the listview by default is hide and only when click a button it will be visible....

Comment: `bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN); ` hides the list view container

Comment: No man I dont understand me I have other views in the bottomsheet and I want hide /visible only the listview by a button outside from the bottomsheet

Comment: Update your question by posting your xml too, to get a better vision of the problem